# Formik setFieldValue is not updating state immediately (1 render behind)

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a formik form setup with initial values of `{ email: "", password: "", method: "manual" }`. I would like to change the value of method to 'google' inside the onSuccess in my GoogleLogin component from react-oauth/google. After changing the value I submit the form manually using submitForm method.

The issue that I am facing is that the setFieldValue is not changing on the first form submission. I don't want to use a seperate state to handle this. What am I doing wrong here?

```
export const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [login] = useLoginMutation(); // First item is data state
  return (
    <Wrapper variant="small">
      <Formik
        enableReinitialize={true} // I tried setting it to false
        initialValues={{ email: "", password: "", method: "manual" }}
        onSubmit={async (values, { setErrors }) => {
          console.log("form values", values);
          const response = await login({
            variables: { options: values },
            update: (cache, { data }) => {
              cache.writeQuery<MeQuery>({
                query: MeDocument,
                data: {
                  __typename: "Query",
                  me: data?.login.user,
                },
              });
              cache.evict({ fieldName: "posts:{}" });
            },
          });

          if (response.data?.login.errors) {
            setErrors(toErrorMap(response.data.login.errors));
          } else if (response.data?.login.user) {
            if (typeof router.query.next === "string") {
              router.push(router.query.next);
            } else {
              // worked
              router.push("/");
            }
          }
        }}
      >
        {({ isSubmitting, submitForm, setFieldValue, setFieldTouched }) => (
          <Form>
            <InputField name="email" label="Email" placeholder="john@gmail.com" />
            <Box mt={4}>
              <InputField
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                placeholder="Password"
                type={"password"}
              />
            </Box>
            <Flex>
              <Box mt={4} ml={"auto"}>
                <NextLink href="/forgot-password">
                  <Link textColor={"blue.600"} href="/forgot-password">
                    Forgot password?
                  </Link>
                </NextLink>
              </Box>
            </Flex>

            <Button
              mt={4}
              w="100%"
              type="submit"
              isLoading={isSubmitting}
              colorScheme="teal"
              onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
              }}
            >
              Login
            </Button>

            <GoogleLogin
              onSuccess={(response) => {
                setFieldValue("method", "google");
                setTimeout(() => setFieldTouched("method", true));
                submitForm();
              }}
              onError={() => {}}
            ></GoogleLogin>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: You are calling `setFieldValue` and then submitting the form directly after. Generally, updating state in react is not synchronous. If we assume formik keeps some internal state it makes sense that is does not update until after a rerender.

Comment: I fixed it by wrapping the submitForm with a setTimeout. Not the cleanest solution but I didn't want to redo my form for this. Thought about using UE but I can't submit my form from outside of the Formik componenet unless I am using useFormik.

Comment: UE? As an alternative you can wrap `GoogleLogin` in your own component that uses `useFormik`. That's usually how I build custom components that integrates with formik.

Comment: Use Effect. Can you give me an example on how how you would go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach you could take by using `useFormikContext`.

```
export function GoogleLoginSubmitOnSuccess() {
    const { values, submitForm, setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (values.method === "google") {
            submitForm()
        }
    }, [values, submitForm])

    return (
        <GoogleLogin
            onSuccess={(response) => {
                setFieldValue("method", "google");
            }}
            onError={() => {}}
        />
    )
}
```

You could also do the same thing with `useField` if you want to make it more reusable/customizable.